# Navigation Property is null by Find method of DataContext in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

I have two entities one is `Users` and another is `UserProfile`, both have one to one relationship. I am accessing using `Find()` method of `DataContext` such as.

```
public T GetById(object id)
{
   return this.Entities.Find(id);
}
```

But each time I an getting `UserProfile` `null`. Please help !

Comment: After spent some hours I find out that I am using one to one relationship for both entities. To get navigation properties data on load on base entity I need to define it virtual property. After UserProfile property define a virtual property in User entity then I am able to navigation property data.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot load related entities by `Find` method. while you want get related entities you could explicitly load it.

```
var post = context.Posts.Find(2); 
context.Entry(post).Reference(p => p.Blog).Load();
```

Or use `SingleOrDefault|FirstOrdefault` with `Include` method.

And generic way to load navigation property

```
public TEntity GetItem(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    var query = context.EntitySet<TEntity>().AsQueryable();
    if (includeProperties != null)
        query = ApplyIncludesOnQuery(query, includeProperties);

    return query.SingleOrDefault(predicate);
}

internal static IQueryable<TEntity> ApplyIncludesOnQuery(IQueryable<TEntity> query, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    // Return Applied Includes query
    return (includeProperties.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include)));
}
```

Comment: There are any generic way to add navigation properties data to many entity like we can add Blog data in Post in generic way as per my question example?